Query Attribute Error with Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.1 when using the pagination method
I am using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy version 3.1 for a book library. The index.html page has a table that displays the title, author, and ISBN of each book. I would like to use the SQLAlchemy pagination method to display the books over multiple pages, with 10 books per page. However, I am receiving an AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'paginate' for the statement:
book_data = books_query.paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)

Here is my code for the index route in routes.py:
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, session, request
from books.database import Session
from books.models import Book, Author, Genre, Location, Publisher, Tag, Format
pages = Blueprint(
"pages", name, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static"
)
@pages.route("/")
def index():
    session = Session()

    # Get the page number from the query parameter
    page = request.args.get("page", 1, type=int)
    # Number of books per page
    per_page = 10  

    # Query to join Books and Authors tables
    books_query = session.query(
        Book.id,
        Book.title,
        Book.isbn,
        Author.first_name,
        Author.last_name
    ).join(Author, Author.id == Book.author_id)

    # Execute the query and paginate the results 
    book_data = books_query.paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)

    # Close the session
    session.close()    

    return render_template(
        "index.html",
        title="Book Library",
        page_title="Library Catalog",
        book_data = book_data
    )


I tried to modify the above code by combining the query and the execution statements.
    # Paginate the results
    book_data = session.query(
        Book.id,
        Book.title,
        Book.isbn,
        Author.first_name,
        Author.last_name
    ).join(Author, Author.id == Book.author_id).paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)

But I still get the AttributeError for the query.
I can successfully display all the books without pagination using the code:
book_data = books_query.all()
Also all the other page queries work correctly. So the connection to the database is working properly. Most of the resources on pagination I found refer to the older (v2.0) versions of Flash SQLAlchemy. They mostly assume that I have a db instance rather than a session instance created with the Session object defined in my database.py file. here is the database.py code.
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

load_dotenv()

# Configure database URL 
DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI')

# Create the engine
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI)

# Create a session factory
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

I assume that there is a difference on implementing the pagination with version 3.1.
Here is part of my requirements.txt file.
Flask==3.0.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
SQLAlchemy==2.0.30

Any help on modifying the code is much appreciated.

In Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.1.x, the function paginate() is no longer assigned to the query, but to the SQLAlchemy instance. However, it is still possible to use the Legacy Query Interface, but I advise against using it.
The documentation also states:

The statement should select a model class, like select(User). This applies unique() and scalars() modifiers to the result, so compound selects will not return the expected results.

For this reason, I recommend that you create a relationship within your models.
class Author(db.Model):
    id:Mapped[int] = db.mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    last_name:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    books:Mapped[List['Book']] = db.relationship(back_populates='author')

class Book(db.Model):
    id:Mapped[int] = db.mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    isbn:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(13), nullable=False, unique=True)
    author_id:Mapped[int]= db.mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'), nullable=False)
    author:Mapped['Author'] = db.relationship(back_populates='books')

Even if you only ask for all books in the query, you can use the defined relationship to reach the author and the name properties.
<table>
    {% for book in pagination -%}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ book.author.first_name }} {{ book.author.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ book.isbn }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor -%}
</table>

You can find information on using pagination with Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.1.x here in the documentation and here in a highly recommended tutorial.
If you use the above suggestion regarding the use of relationship definitions within the models, your code could look like this.
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase, 
    Mapped 
)
from typing import List

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db'
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app, model_class=Base)

class Author(db.Model):
    id:Mapped[int] = db.mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    last_name:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    books:Mapped[List['Book']] = db.relationship(back_populates='author')

class Book(db.Model):
    id:Mapped[int] = db.mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    isbn:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(13), nullable=False, unique=True)
    author_id:Mapped[int]= db.mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'), nullable=False)
    author:Mapped['Author'] = db.relationship(back_populates='books')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    per_page = 10  

    pagination = db.paginate(
        db.select(Book).order_by(Book.title, Book.isbn), 
        page=page, 
        per_page=per_page, 
        error_out=False
    )

    return render_template(
        'index.html', 
        **locals()
    )


Thanks Detief. As you can see, I'm using sessionmaker to create a Session class in the database,py file. This is imported in to my routes.py file to create session instances for the queues. I used your suggestion on using the updated pagination function. However, I still get the Attribute Error, but now for the session instance. It looks like pagination only works with the SQLAlchemy instance not he session.

@wmiller There are alternative ways to implement pagination. Take a look at DataTables or, what I haven't used yet and therefore can't recommend, is Flask-Paginate.
